# Running two hosts files at the same time

Tags: macos, hosts-file

I am developing on my local machine and I need to have a browser run on one host file and another browser run on a different host file.

One browser would run a host file to redirect domain.com to my local machine.
The second browser would run a host file to redirect domain.com to a external product server.

Is this possible?

Btw, I can't rename the local machine to lets say this.domain.com

I'm running mac os x

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: I know many Unices, but not Darwin/MacOS Xvery well, so some of the details may differ...

You have a few options to achieve your aim, though not necessarily by the method you describe:

- run a virtual machine for the second browser
- run a 'virtualised applcation' for the second browser (I do not know  what, if any, application-virtualisation options exist for MacOS X)
- run a second browser in a chrooted environment, though you would need to populate the chroot with a lot of bits of the OS for something like a graphical browser to run
- configure one browser to use a proxy running on another machine which has different lookup information
- hook something which alters the response of a gethostbyname() call, e.g. `LD_PRELOAD=/my/special/libresolv.so /path/to/browser` (the browser, like any other application does not, AIUI, read /etc/hosts directly, instead it calls gethostbyname() which is handled by libresolv which will read /etc/hosts or talk to DNS servers or other name-lookup facilities)

There might be 'sandboxed' browsers for MacOS X, usually intended for security however they might be based on an abstraction layer between browser and OS that gives you a useful starting point.

Comment: +1 for running a virtual machine with the second browser.  I actually find it useful to have a virtual machine running the exact same setup as the live machine so I'm sure it will work in both places.